# Why set customCell property to nil using UINib

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uinib

I'm looking at some Apple sample code using the UINib method for cellForRowAtIndexPath for UITableView:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
        static NSString *QuoteCellIdentifier = @"QuoteCellIdentifier";
        QuoteCell *cell = (QuoteCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:QuoteCellIdentifier];
        if (!cell) {
                UINib *quoteCellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"QuoteCell" bundle:nil];
        [quoteCellNib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
        cell = self.quoteCell;
        self.quoteCell = nil;
```

I don't quite understand the last two lines

```
        cell = self.quoteCell;
        self.quoteCell = nil;
```

Can someone explain what is happening in those last two lines?  thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look at this line:

```
[quoteCellNib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
```

That is saying to the NIB to instantiate with the current object as the owner. Presumably in your NIB you have set the file's owner class properly and have an `IBOutlet` property in that class called `quoteCell`. So when you instantiate the NIB it will set that property in your instance, i.e. it's setting `self.quoteCell` to be the newly created cell.

But you don't want to keep the property pointing to that cell because you've just used it as a temporary variable to get access to the cell. So you set `cell` to be `self.quoteCell` so that you can then return it from that function. Then you don't need `self.quoteCell` anymore so you get rid of it.

[By the way, I assume this is using ARC? Otherwise you will want to retain `cell` and then autorelease it.]